# Mac App Interface Design with XCode

Tags: macos, user-interface, interface-builder

I'm building a Mac App. How do I do interface designs for this? Do I use that Interface Builder? Any good tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Aaron Hillegass' book "Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X" is a great tutorial, lots of working examples. It's only 20 bucks on kindle.

Okay, there are plenty of online tutorials, including from Apple, but a good book like this will get you up to speed way faster.